# How to produce JSON with sorted keys in Go?

Tags: json, go

In python you can produce JSON with keys in sorted order by doing

```
import json
print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I have not found a similar option in Go. Any ideas how I can achieve similar behavior in go?

Comment: can you please post the solution you used ? I tried using `NewEncoder(...).Encode(structInstance)` but the output json keys are not sorted.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The json package always orders keys when marshalling. Specifically:

- Maps have their keys sorted lexicographically
- Structs keys are marshalled in the order defined in the struct

The implementation lives here ATM:

- http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/encode.go?#L359

Comment: Noice. I wonder why the encoding/json documentation doesn't mention this crucial property.

Comment: Now it is documented : https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal : Map values encode as JSON objects. The map's key type must either be a string, an integer type, or implement encoding.TextMarshaler. The map keys are sorted and used as JSON object keys by applying the following rules, subject to the UTF-8 coercion described for string values above

Comment: What about the struct keys? Is the order documented?

Comment: Radik provided a great answer below. To get the struct keys sorted, you either need to do use his `JsonRemarshal` function (which will incur additional time penalty), or write your own implementation of `Marshal` using reflection.

Answer (score 13):

Gustavo Niemeyer gave great answer, just a small handy snippet I use to validate and reorder/normalize []byte representation of json when required

```golang
func JSONRemarshal(bytes []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    var ifce interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &ifce)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return json.Marshal(ifce)
}
```

Comment: Does not order elements in json array. I'm using Go 1.19.5.

Comment: and it shouldn't, slices (arrays) in both json and go have particular order, while maps are indexed. In fact, you can say that order of items in array *is* data. The original question is about "keys" hence maps. Reordering an array would be considered a bug.