# Write a prettyPrinted JSON object with sorted keys in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

We often want to use JSON for human readability. As such, it is common to ask to sort the JSON keys alphabetically (or alphanumerically) [in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668652/how-to-produce-json-with-sorted-keys-in-go), [in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417235/c-sharp-sort-json-string-keys), [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774361/json-output-sorting-in-python), [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952571/jackson-jsonnode-to-string-with-sorted-keys), ...

**But how to output a JSON with JSON keys sorted alphabetically in Swift?**

PrettyPrinted output is easy:

```
JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(jsonObject, to: outputStream, options: [.prettyPrinted], error: nil)
```

Yet the keys are not alphabetically sorted for human readability. They are likely in the order given by [NSDictionary.keyEnumerator()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1411011-keyenumerator). But sadly, we can't subclass Dictionary, NSDictionary or CFDictionary in Swift, so we can't override the behavior of keys order.

<sub>[edit: actually, we can subclass NSDictionary, see one of my answers below]</sub>

Comment: By design, dictionaries aren't sorted in any way. If order matters to you, you should use an array.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez it is a common pattern for human readability to desire to sort the keys.

Comment: In the latest (currently beta) SDKs (iOS 11, macOS 10.13, etc.), there is a `.sortedKeys` writing option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For iOS 11+ and macOS High Sierra (10.13+), a new option [.sortedKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization.writingoptions/2888322-sortedkeys) solves the problem easily:

```
JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(jsonObject, to: outputStream, options: [.sortedKeys, .prettyPrinted], error: nil)
```

Thank you [Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish) for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Swift solution for iOS 7+, macOS 10.9+ (OS X Mavericks and up).

A solution is to [subclass NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary) (but not overriding the default `init` method as it wouldn't compile with Swift).

```
class MutableOrderedDictionary: NSDictionary {
    let _values: NSMutableArray = []
    let _keys: NSMutableOrderedSet = []

    override var count: Int {
        return _keys.count
    }
    override func keyEnumerator() -> NSEnumerator {
        return _keys.objectEnumerator()
    }
    override func object(forKey aKey: Any) -> Any? {
        let index = _keys.index(of: aKey)
        if index != NSNotFound {
            return _values[index]
        }
        return nil
    }
    func setObject(_ anObject: Any, forKey aKey: String) {
        let index = _keys.index(of: aKey)
        if index != NSNotFound {
            _values[index] = anObject
        } else {
            _keys.add(aKey)
            _values.add(anObject)
        }
    }
}
```

With it, we can order the keys of our object with `.forcedOrdering` before writing it with `.prettyPrinted`:

```
// force ordering
let orderedJson = MutableOrderedDictionary()
jsonObject.sorted { $0.0.compare($1.0, options: [.forcedOrdering, .caseInsensitive]) == .orderedAscending }
          .forEach { orderedJson.setObject($0.value, forKey: $0.key) }

// write pretty printed
_ = JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(orderedJson, to: outputJSON, options: [.prettyPrinted], error: nil)
```

But be careful: you will need to subclass and sort **all** subdictionaries of your JSON object if you have any. Here is an extension for doing that recursion, inspired by [Evgen Bodunov](/users/241482/evgen-bodunov)'s [gist](https://gist.github.com/molind/94b750bdd6c603d608b2310f6be5f050) (thank you).

```
extension MutableOrderedDictionary {
    private static let defaultOrder: ((String, Any), (String, Any)) -> Bool = {
        $0.0.compare($1.0, options: [.forcedOrdering, .caseInsensitive]) == .orderedAscending
    }
    static func sorted(object: Any, by areInIncreasingOrder: ((key: String, value: Value), (key: String, value: Value)) -> Bool = defaultOrder) -> Any {
        if let dict = object as? [String: Any] {
            return MutableOrderedDictionary(dict, by: areInIncreasingOrder)
        } else if let array = object as? [Any] {
            return array.map { sorted(object: $0, by: areInIncreasingOrder) }
        } else {
            return object
        }
    }
    convenience init(_ dict: [String: Any], by areInIncreasingOrder: ((key: String, value: Value), (key: String, value: Value)) -> Bool = defaultOrder) {
        self.init()
        dict.sorted(by: areInIncreasingOrder)
            .forEach { setObject(MutableOrderedDictionary.sorted(object: $0.value, by: areInIncreasingOrder), forKey: $0.key) }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// force ordering
let orderedJson = MutableOrderedDictionary(jsonObject)

// write pretty printed
_ = JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(orderedJson, to: outputJSON, options: [.prettyPrinted], error: nil)
```

Comment: Great answer. I've updated it to work with recursive objects and made convenience init. https://gist.github.com/molind/94b750bdd6c603d608b2310f6be5f050

Answer (score 1):

Solution for iOS 7+, macOS 10.9+ (OS X Mavericks and up).

A solution is to subclass NSDictionary in **Objective-C**, then use the subclass from a framework (for Application) or static library (for Command Line Tool).

For this demonstration, I will use [nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary/tree/master/OrderedDictionary) (700+ lines of code) instead of doing it from scratch, but there may be untested alternatives like [quinntaylor/CHOrderedDictionary](https://github.com/quinntaylor/CHDataStructures/blob/master/source/CHOrderedDictionary.m) or [rhodgkins/RDHOrderedDictionary](https://github.com/rhodgkins/RDHOrderedDictionary). To integrate it as a Framework, add this dependency in your PodFile:

```
pod 'OrderedDictionary', '~> 1.4'
```

Then we will order the keys of our object:

```
import OrderedDictionary

let orderedJson = MutableOrderedDictionary()
jsonObject.sorted { $0.0.compare($1.0, options: [.forcedOrdering, .caseInsensitive]) == .orderedAscending }
          .forEach { orderedJson.setObject($0.value, forKey: $0.key) }
```

<sup>(note: `setObject(_,forKey:)` is specific to MutableOrderedDictionary)</sup>
And finally we can write it prettyPrinted:

```
_ = JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(orderedJson, to: outputJSON, options: [.prettyPrinted], error: nil)
```

But be careful: you need to subclass and sort **all** subdictionaries of your JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible workaround that works **only for macOS** Swift scripts. It is **not for iOS**.

We workaround Swift Foundation limitations with a different programming language (**Python 2.7** for example).

```
import Cocoa

// sample jsonObject
let jsonObject = ["hello": "world", "foo": "bar"]

// writing JSON to file
let jsonPath = "myJson.json"
let outputJSON = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: jsonPath, append: false)!
outputJSON.open()
_ = JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(jsonObject, to: outputJSON, options: [], error: nil)
outputJSON.close()

// sortedKeys equivalent using `sort_keys=True`
// prettyPrinted equivalent using `indent=2, separators=(',', ' : ')`
// unicode using `io.open` and `ensure_ascii=False`
func shell(_ args: String...) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
shell("python", "-c", ""
    + "import io\n"
    + "import json\n"
    + "jsonPath = 'myJson.json'\n"
    + "with io.open(jsonPath, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as json_file:\n"
    + "    all_data = json.load(json_file)\n"
    + "with io.open(jsonPath, mode='w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:\n"
    + "    json_file.write(unicode(json.dumps(all_data, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ' : '))))\n"
)
```